# ion-item-divider in for loop

Tags: angular, loops, for-loop, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-item-divider` in for loop to display `ion-card` but after the first item it disappears because it's replaced by another ion-item-divider which is no display thanks to my `ngIf`.

for exemple:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let value of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; let i = index">
     <ion-item-divider sticky *ngIf="i === 0 || i === 3">{{value}}</ion-item-divider>
     <ion-card>{{value}}</ion-card>
</ion-item-group>
```

I want my `ion-item-divider` stays until it is replaced by another true `ngIf` and no after each loop.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: please explain bit more what you want to achieve

Comment: I have an array of real_estate which belongs_to sectors. I sort my array by sectors and I want to display this array and ion-item-divider which have the sector name of real_estate. So It works but after one item scroll down my ion-item-divider dissapear